# Using logical operators

Tags: programming

This is a snip it of code from a program I am writing. I have the program turn an LED on and if a button is pressed when the LED is on I want it to add to a counter and print the counter value. The problem seems that my if statement is skipped. Right now the while loop is setup for 5 seconds using millis() and stays off using a short delay. This part (button_press_9())) is a function call to a Boolean I have setup for debouncing. If I put the function call in an if statement by its self for example to test it. It works and will turn an LED on and off. It seems the combination of the two is incompatible.

Thank you in advance.

```
unsigned long previousMillis = millis();
unsigned long currentMillis = millis();

while ((currentMillis - previousMillis) < onTime)
{
    digitalWrite(ledPin4, HIGH);
    if (ledPin4 == HIGH && (button_press_9()))
    {
        counter++;
        Serial.println(counter);
        currentMillis = onTime * 100;
    }
    currentMillis = millis();
}
digitalWrite(ledPin4, LOW);
delay(1000);
```

Comment: ledPin4 == HIGH? Guess you mean something else.

Comment: Also, `currentMillis = onTime * 100;` makes little sense. What did you actually _mean_?

Comment: @EdgarBonet I put it in there so if the LED was HIGH and there button pushed it would end the timer in the while loop

Comment: @MikaelPatel I set the LED to HIGH and then used an if statement to check if it's HIGH and the button was pressed at the same time. I didn't use there == to assign the HIGH state

Comment: Then you mean `currentMillis = previousMillis + onTime`, but that won't work because you assign `currentMillis = millis();` right after. Instead, you can simply `break` out of the `while` loop.

Comment: `ledPin4 == HIGH` does not check if the LED is high. For instance, if ledPin4 is defined as `int ledPin4 = 4;` then the statement is `4 == 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
if (digitalRead(ledPin4) == HIGH && (button_press_9()))
```

instead of

```
if (ledPin4 == HIGH && (button_press_9()))
```

Comment: Since the pin has been set to `HIGH` right before, the first part of the test seems useless. You can just do `if (button_press_9())`.